# Can't seem to get Contact Form Script to work

Tags: php, contact-form

Pastie with the PHP code: http://pastie.org/6427151

Pastie with the HTML form: http://pastie.org/6427155

Any idea why this doesn't work? It spits out 'Please fill out all of the fields.' even though the fields are all filled out correctly. I know very little about PHP so it could very well be something simple. I use this same script on another website though, and it works fine there, which I why I'm perplexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input fields in your `form`'s markup need `name` attributes.  The `name` attribute works as a key to access the value within the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array that is submitted by the user.

So you need to have:

```
<form ... method="post">
...
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" ... />
...
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" ... />
...
<textarea name="message" id="message" ... ></textarea>
```

Which you then access using each `name` (case-sensitive):

```
$name = $_POST['name']; // not $_POST['Name'], or $_GET['name']
```

Also be sure to *carefully* validate and sanitize all userland-submitted content you process.

Comment: Just a note for others able to make this mistake, the `placeholder` attribute is not a wedge for a default `value` of your form element. If you want the `input` to *have a default value* that you give it (from a row in a table maybe), you have to put that value into the markup, such as `value="look ma, no hands!"`. What may be in `placeholder` attribute will **not** be sent back to your script when submitted, it is (literally) only for looks.

Comment: I, um, made some edits. Something I always try to do is front load the `type`, `name`, and `id` attributes right after the beginning of the element. It is possible to forget and put two of the same attribute in one element, so this just makes it easier to see them when reading the code.

Comment: Wow. Haha, I knew it would be something simple... For some unknown reason I was thinking that was what 'for' was doing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

First, define `name` attributes to all `input`, `textarea`, `select` and `button` elements you want to submit data back from your form.

I also recommend you use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with a `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` flag to ***best*** process what is presented to your script:

```
// If invalid, this will return nothing.
// If valid, the email address as a string.
function validateEmail($eamil) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

This is ***best practice*** and ***more secure*** than the scripted versions you'll find around. There are other worthwhile filter and validation flags available for this function as well.

Comment: Not just `input`s. `textarea`s, `select`s and `button`s (careful with those) too.

Comment: Can you tell me what the difference is? Is that so people can't take the email it is being sent to from the script?

Comment: @Jared - Do you mean `filter_var()`? I'm not sure what you mean by *take the email being sent to them* (unless you mean snooping on the request between your user's browser and your server, something called a *man-in-the-middle attack*), you do this because ***you trust nothing from userland!!!*** and **always** *validate, compare and/or sanitize all data* arriving at your server's script from userland. This is to protect your server and your site's users by proxy (who may get infected by XSS or their data stolen from your database).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `name` attribute in all `input` type.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="full" required name="name" id="name" />
```

`name` attribute value is related to `$_POST` , after define `name attribute` you can get value of `$_POST['name']`.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to define `name attributes` for all input fields.

The `name attribute` specifies the name of an `<input>` element.

The `name attribute` is used to reference elements in a **JavaScript**, or **to reference form data after a form is submitted.**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="full" required id="name" />
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="full" required id="email" />
<textarea id="message" cols="30" name="message" rows="10" class="full"></textarea>
```